# FTP connect with no username and password?

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

Hello I have connected to the FTP using `URLConnection` with just the IP address with not specifing the login credentials.

```
URLConnection conn = new URLConnection(new URL("ftp://222.101.102.1/etc"));
```

It works, with no credentials because the server probably allows annonymous connection.

But for practice I wanted to make an ftp connection from scratch with `Socket` client, and I created a new socket connection to that IP:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("222.101.102.1", 21);
if (socket != null) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String version = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(version);
}
```

This prints `220 vsFTPd (2.0.5)`

but when I try to do command like `LS \r\n`

I get `530 Please login with USER and PASS`

Why is it asking me for login if with `URLConnection` it did not?

*This code was not compiled because it was memorized from my other computer so let me know if you notice something wrong and I'll edit right away.*

Comment: IIRC, When you build a socket, you are building the whole workings around a protocol, but you have to setup how it will communicate over that protocol. When you build the URLConnection object, you are creating an object that already has those workings built into it. In other words, URLConnection knows how to connect and login, but in the Socket you are building, it only knows how to physically connect. It doesn't know what to do next.

Comment: @blahfunk Thats exactly what I need! I need the information on how URLConnection does it, what does it use as default connection credentials where do I get that information ? People say username is annonymous or ftp and password as email but we don't use emails there not that I know of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

`URL.openConnection()` basically returns a class that implements `URLStreamHandler` based on the protocol. So in this case the protocol is `ftp`and it returns `FtpURLConnection`.

So there is a check that if the username is null (not specified in the URL), and if it is so it sets it to anonymous and uses a password of the java version with @

e.g `Java1.8.0@` not sure for what purpose, maybe for login history.
But you can use any password to login with anonymous unless it's configured for something else I think.

```
        if(this.user == null) {
            this.user = "anonymous";
            String var11 = (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("java.version"));
            this.password = (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("ftp.protocol.user", "Java" + var11 + "@"));
        }
```

So I basically logged in with `Anonymous` and **no password**.